# Android Studio 再インストール後、エラー発生

Tags: java, android-studio

Android Studio 再インストール後、システム立ち上げ時、下記メッセージ発生して、
システム立ち上げせず。回復手順を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

**システム構成:**

- windows 10 64ビット RAM 4GB
- Android Studio 3.1

`java -version`の実行結果は下記のとおりです。

```
> java -version
java version "10" 2018-03-20 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: JAVA_HOME は設定しましたか？

Comment: JAVA_HOMEを\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161、と　C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre　同様エラー発生しました

Comment: なるほど。。JDK は64bit のものを入れましたか？またCMD でJava --version を入力するとどうなりますか？

Comment: パスのはじめに C: がついてないのはコピペ等のミスですか？それとも実際にそれいれたんですか？

Comment: 再度jdk、android studio をインストールしても、同様にエラーが、そこで、cがつながっていないのは、コピーミスです、java -versio 下記のとおりです、Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.334]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\vaiot>java -version
java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)

Comment: Java10 ですね？Android Studio がサポートしてない可能性があります。

Answer (score 3):

Java10を使う方法への回答にはなっていないですが、開発をするための回答をします。

現在Android StudioはまだJava10をサポートしていない、もしくはWindows10の環境下でバグがある可能性があるかもしれません。
JDK10について、stackoverflowの質問やjetbrainsのレポートを見つけました。
[Android Studio not detecting JDK-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519137/android-studio-not-detecting-jdk-10)
[idea64-does-not-work-with-jdk-10-on-Windows-10](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000164664-idea64-does-not-work-with-jdk-10-on-Windows-10)

Stackoverflowの質問の方は3.1で動作した　というふうに書いています。
が、jetbrainsのレポートではWindows10では動作せず、Windows8では動作したとあります(こちらはIntellij IDEA 2018.1の話です)

Android studio 自体はintelliJをベースに作られているので、同じ現象がtmomoさんのローカルにも発生しているのかもしれません。

また、もし使えたとしてもJava10どころかJava9の機能もAndroid studioでは使えないと思います。
[Does android studio 3 support java 9 for android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627499/does-android-studio-3-support-java-9-for-android-development)

Android StudioのUserGuide等をみても、Java8のものしか見つけられませんでした。
[Java8 support features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features)

なので、現時点ではJava8を使うと問題なくAndroidStudioを起動できると思います。

Comment: jdk10を削除してjdk8でしてみる

Comment: jdk8をインストールしましが、同様にエラーが発生しました

Comment: @tmomo JAVA_HOME はJava8 のものに変更しましたか？

Comment: java8にインスールしました、

Comment: java8とjdk8は、同じですか

Comment: @tmomo JDK8はJava8 です。Java development kit の略で、開発時に必要となるものです。JAVA_HOMEの値はなににしましたか？

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 にしました

Comment: @tmomo エラーに表示されるPath は変更したものになってますか？

Comment: エラーメッセージのpathに設定しました、エラーは、同様でした

Comment: @tmomo java --version確認できますか？

Comment: いろいろ実施したが、エラー発生するので様子をみたい、回答者へありがとうございます。